About Boolean operation Difference
I'm facing a issue about difference boolean operation (Polygon A / Polygon B). When a polygon is not simple, the CGAL::difference() function has a crash. Look the example of a question that I facing.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "print_utils.hpp"
/* The function print_polygon_with_holes taken from print_utils.h
 * component distributed by CGAL developers. This header was 
 * encontered at /cgal/Minkowski_sum_2/example/Minkowski_sum_2/ 
*/

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_with_holes_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Boolean_set_operations_2.h>
#include <CGAL/convex_hull_2.h>

using Kernel                = CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel;
using FT                    = Kernel::FT;
using Point_2               = Kernel::Point_2;
using Segment_2             = Kernel::Segment_2;
using Polygon_2             = CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel>;
using Polygon_with_holes_2  = CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2<Kernel>;
using VertexIterator        = Polygon_2::Vertex_iterator;
using VectorOfPoints        = std::vector<Point_2>;
using Pwh_2_container       = std::vector<Polygon_with_holes_2>;

int main(void)
{
  Polygon_2 A;
  A.push_back(Point_2(12, 12));
  A.push_back(Point_2(10, 12));
  A.push_back(Point_2(8, 10));
  A.push_back(Point_2(8, 4));
  A.push_back(Point_2(8, 9));
  A.push_back(Point_2(6, 12));
  A.push_back(Point_2(4, 12));
  A.push_back(Point_2(2, 12));
  A.push_back(Point_2(0, 10));
  A.push_back(Point_2(0, 0));
  A.push_back(Point_2(0, -2));
  A.push_back(Point_2(2, -4));
  A.push_back(Point_2(4, -4));
  A.push_back(Point_2(14, -4));
  A.push_back(Point_2(16, -1));
  A.push_back(Point_2(16, 9));

  VectorOfPoints            ch_points_A;
  VectorOfPoints::iterator  ch_it;
  Polygon_2                 B;

  CGAL::convex_hull_2(A.vertices_begin(), A.vertices_end(), std::back_inserter(ch_points_A));

  for (ch_it = ch_points_A.begin(); ch_it != ch_points_A.end(); ++ch_it) {
    B.push_back(*ch_it);
  }

  Pwh_2_container diff;

  if (A.is_simple()) {
    CGAL::difference(B, A, std::back_inserter(diff));
  } else {
    std::cout << "The polygon A is not simple\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  std::cout << "Printing the Difference A / B\n";
  for (auto p : diff) {
    print_polygon_with_holes(p);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Anyone has ideia why this happens?
I still don't have any ideas on how to avoid this situation.

When the polygon is not simple, difference is not called!?

No. If called, cause a crash. Try it! Strip out the if () that evolves CGAL::difference() function.

Your polygon A is degenerate, with overlapping collinear edges (see your third through fifth points). Looks like difference() doesn't handle that case. You'll need to clean up the degeneracies first. (Not a difficult task; just look for runs of three collinear points, and when you find such a run, remove the middle point).

You might want to try the polygon repair package introduced in CGAL 6.0

To @Sneftel : I used the CGAL::difference() function in the hope of getting this degenerate polygon as a result. Maybe I'm not understanding the function's documentation or this function really can't handle degenerate polygons.

I’m not sure what you mean by that. I’m taking about your input to difference(), not the output.

The conditions that the input of CGAL::difference() (and all other functions in this package) are clearly listed in the user manual; see Sections 2.1 and 2.2. One of them states that the input polygon must be simple.
